# Maven with docker, "Non-resolvable parent POM" for parent-child project

Tags: java, docker, maven, pom.xml

I'm making microservice project, so parent project, named *obshaga* contains only pom.xml and modules (microservices). So I wanted to make this easy to deploy by using docker-compose, so first of all I made dockerfile in every project. For example, for example in microservice "tg-dispatcher" I wrote this Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src

RUN ["./mvnw", "install"]

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "./target/tg-dispatcher.jar"]
```

`pom.xml` for parent project *obshaga*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.dompurrr</groupId>
    <artifactId>obshaga</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>tg-dispatcher</module>
        <module>node</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <telegrambot.starter.version>6.1.0</telegrambot.starter.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*IT*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`pom.xml` for child project *tg-dispatcher*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.dompurrr</groupId>
        <artifactId>obshaga</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>tg-dispatcher</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${telegrambot.starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>tg-dispatcher</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So when I try to build docker image for *tg-dispatcher*, I occure error:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.dompurrr:tg-dispatcher:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.dompurrr:obshaga:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.dompurrr:tg-dispatcher:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/app/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.dompurrr:tg-dispatcher:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.dompurrr:obshaga:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

I can easily `maven package` or `maven install` this outside of docker and do other things, so problem for me is to put all of this and orginise it inside docker.

I found out that I might try to deploy parent project artifact to maven central, but it seems to be strange solution.
Is there way to deploy it locally or inside docker container maybe?
Or maybe there's other ways to solve this problem? Maybe i can re-organise project, so every microservice wouldn't be connected to parent project?

Comment: Why do you want to run the build in a docker container? Why not use a build server like Jenkins, Gitlab CI, GitHub actions?

Comment: @JFabianMeier To be honest, I forgot about this tools. Anyway, I didn't use them unlike docker, so it will take some time to learn them